# Start Selenium Server with Firefox Portable

Tags: firefox, selenium

I want to use Selenium Server on Windows 7 with a FirefoxPortable as browser, starting the `selenium-server-standalon` JAR file. My first attempt was without a profile, just like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar 
     -htmlSuite "*firefox C:\Users\rplantik\Portables\selenium\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe" 
      "http://127.0.0.1"    
      "C:\Users\rplantik\Portables\selenium\rest\testsuite.html" 
      "testresults.html"
```

The Jetty server was started, but it crushed after having issued the info message `Preparing Firefox profile...`

I found out that there is another portable app, called FirefoxPortable2ndProfile, which allows you to start FirefoxPortable with another than the built-in profile. I therefore downloaded that application, too, and modified the command as follows, to include the path to the different profile:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar 
     -firefoxProfileTemplate C:\Users\rplantik\Portables\selenium\FirefoxPortable2ndProfile\Data\profile 
     -htmlSuite "*firefox C:\Users\rplantik\Portables\selenium\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe" 
      "http://127.0.0.1"    
      "C:\Users\rplantik\Portables\selenium\rest\testsuite.html" 
      "testresults.html"
```

Now it seems that the profile was created successfully (`Preparing Firefox profile...` seems to be executed as intended - for a short moment, the "Firefox" logo pops up), then the message `Launching Firefox...` appears, and indeed a firefox application is started.

But after that, the test suite is not executed. Instead, the browser stays on the default site, and there is no further action until I stop the process in the console.

How to use Selenium with Firefox Portable?

Comment: I signed in to sqa.stackexchange.com and copied the question:  http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6619/how-to-start-selenium-with-firefox-portable

Answer (score 1):

Point to the profile folder of the portable installation:
(C:\selenium\firefox_portable-14.0.1\Data)
ie.
C:\selenium\server>java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "C:\selenium\firefox_portable-14.0.1\Data"

Additional info here:
http://portableapps.com/node/5376

NOTE: I had to close all Firefox windows before running the tests. Otherwise the latest version of Firefox is launched.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, specifying the profile has no effect: Firefox is started, but stays on the start screen - the test suite is not executed. I have still no idea why. Were you able to run a test script from the command line?